# Overlay trimmed video with delay causes delay in audio

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I am trying to overlay a video on the top of another with following conditions

- Only specific part of video should be used e.g., 10-50 second for a
  100 second video
- There should be a delay before overlay video start

But issue is that audio of overlaid video is out of sync with video and plays before video
Here is a sample command I am using to trim video for 14 seconds and then overlay it after 10 seconds delay

```
ffmpeg -y -i main_video.mp4 \
    -itsoffset 10.0 -ss 30.0 -t 13.99 -i "foreground_video.mp4" \
    -filter_complex \
    "[1:v]scale=156:86[sv1];[0:v][sv1]overlay=33:156:shortest=1:enable='between(t,10.0,13.99)'[overlay0];\
    [1:a]adelay=10000|10000[1ad];[0:a][1ad]amix=inputs=2[outa]" \
    -map [overlay0] -map [outa] test.mp4
```

If I remove `-ss 30.0 -t 13.99` from command then video overlay with correct audio but I want specific part of video only.

Following are sample videos I used
[foreground_video.mp4](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_QgeNkGmAdNIw7gEN_IqceeDQ9Bpt60w)
[main_video.mp4](https://drive.google.com/open?id=19lzL2uekR1uJE_LM7wdMxuPQhjkw6x_2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

itsoffset + adelay will produce unexpected results viz gaps in the resulting stream. <s>Use asetpts to remove the offset before applying adelay.</s> -ss also interferes when transcoding. So, skip the itsoffset and apply individual setpts filter for the video and adelay for the audio.

Use

```
ffmpeg -y -i main_video.mp4 \
    -ss 30.0 -t 13.99 -i "foreground_video.mp4" \
    -filter_complex \
    "[1:v]scale=156:86,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+10.00/TB[sv1];[0:v][sv1]overlay=33:156:shortest=1:enable='between(t,10.0,13.99)'[overlay0];\
     [1:a]adelay=10000|10000[1ad];[0:a][1ad]amix=inputs=2[outa]" \
    -map [overlay0] -map [outa] test.mp4
```

Comment: thank you for answer but I audio is still out of sync, I have updated my question with sample videos, and following is updated command
`ffmpeg -y -i VID-20180807-WA0000.mp4  \
-itsoffset 2.0 -ss 10.0 -t 11.99 -i "RollinWildShort FunnyAnimatedClipsFilmAcademyBW FullHD.mp4"  \
-filter_complex "[1:v]scale=156:86[sv1];[0:v][sv1]overlay=33:156:enable='between(t,2.0,13.99)'[overlay0];[1:a]asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS,adelay=2000|2000[1ad];[0:a][1ad]amix=inputs=2[outa]" -map [overlay0] -map [outa] test.mp4`

Comment: Command edited.

Comment: I have also noticed that we should use `setpts` for the video and `adelay` for the audio. Does anyone know why `setpts` for video + `asetpts` for audio, which would seem logical, fails? See the *"More details"* part [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66256414/mixing-various-audio-and-video-sources-into-a-single-video) for a description of how it fails.

Comment: amix does not work with asetpts-modified audio as expected.